# How to send data with POST method in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, post

I'm having a problem, I want to send data using the POST API method. Here I have several parameters that must be sent, namely in the form of list, string, int, date time and others.

I've tried the example from the flutter documentation and it works because it only sends parameters which are Strings, but in my case I have to send quite a lot of data with different data types. and there is an error if it is filled with null, because all forms are required to be filled from the server.

I want to know if anyone here has experienced a similar case or provide an example of how to send data using the POST API method. I am very frustrated and confused because I haven't finished it for days, I tried looking for it but haven't found a case with what I'm currently experiencing.
Please help
Thank You.

[image]

> respons failed update data

[image]

> Post API

```
Future<UserBiodata> sendBiodata(
    String? stAgama,
    // List<Agama>? agama,
    String? stKwn,
    // List<Kwn>? kwn,
    String? tempat,
    String? tglLahir,
    String? nik,
    String? nisn,
    String? npwp,
    String? jalan,
    String? stProv,
    // List<Province>? province,
    String? stKab,
    // List<Province>? kab,
    String? stKec,
    // List<Province>? kec,
    String? desa,
    String? dusun,
    String? rt,
    String? rw,
    String? kodePos,
    dynamic telp,
    String? email,
    String kps,
    String? stTrans,
    // List<Trans>? trans,
    String? stJn,
    // List<Jn>? jn,
    String? ipk,
    // int? smt,
    String? namaAyah,
    String? nikAyah,
    String? tglLahirAyah,
    String? stPendidikanAyah,
    // List<PendidikanAyah>? pendidikanAyah,
    String? pekerjaanAyah,
    String? penghasilanAyah,
    String? namaIbu,
    String? nikIbu,
    String? tglLahirIbu,
    String? stPendidikanIbu,
    // List<PendidikanIbu>? pendidikanIbu,
    String? pekerjaanIbu,
    String? penghasilanIbu,
    String? namaWali,
    String? nikWali,
    String? tglLahirWali,
    String? stPendidikanWali,
    // List<PendidikanWali>? pendidikanWali,
    String? pekerjaanWali,
    String? penghasilanWali,
  ) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/biodata/update',
      ),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        "st_agama": stAgama,
        // 'agama': agama,
        'st_kwn': stKwn,
        // 'kwn': kwn,
        "tempat": tempat,
        "tgl_lahir": tglLahir,
        "nik": nik,
        "nisn": nisn,
        "npwp": npwp,
        "jalan": jalan,
        "st_prov": stProv,
        // 'province': province,
        "st_kab": stKab,
        // 'kab': kab,
        "st_kec": stKec,
        // 'kec': kec,
        "desa": desa,
        "dusun": dusun,
        "rt": rt,
        "rw": rw,
        "kode_pos": kodePos,
        "telp": telp,
        "email": email,
        "kps": kps,
        "st_trans": stTrans,
        // 'trans': trans,
        "st_jn": stJn,
        // "jn": jn,
        "ipk": ipk,
        // "smt": smt,
        "nama_ayah": namaAyah,
        "nik_ayah": nikAyah,
        "tgl_lahir_ayah": tglLahirAyah,
        "st_pendidikan_ayah": stPendidikanAyah,
        // "pendidikan_ayah": pendidikanAyah,
        "pekerjaan_ayah": pekerjaanAyah,
        "penghasilan_ayah": penghasilanAyah,
        "nama_ibu": namaIbu,
        "nik_ibu": nikIbu,
        "tgl_lahir_ibu": tglLahirIbu,
        "st_pendidikan_ibu": stPendidikanIbu,
        // "pendidikan_ibu": pendidikanIbu,
        "pekerjaan_ibu": pekerjaanIbu,
        "penghasilan_ibu": penghasilanIbu,
        "nama_wali": namaWali,
        "nik_wali": nikWali,
        "tgl_lahir_wali": tglLahirWali,
        "st_pendidikan_wali": stPendidikanWali,
        // "pendidikan_wali": pendidikanWali,
        "pekerjaan_wali": pekerjaanWali,
        "penghasilan_wali": penghasilanWali,
      }),
    );

    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      return UserBiodata.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed update data!');
    }
  }
```

> button send

```
Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _futureBiodata = BiodataProvider().sendBiodata(
                  _controllerAgama.text,
                  // _controller2.text as List<Agama>?,
                  _controllerKwn.text,
                  // _controller4.text as List<Kwn>?,
                  _controllerTmtLahir.text,
                  _controllerTglLahir.text,
                  _controllerNik.text,
                  _controllerNisn.text,
                  _controllerNpwp.text,
                  _controllerAlamat.text,
                  _controllerProv.text,
                  // _controller12.text as List<Province>?,
                  _controllerKab.text,
                  // _controller14.text as List<Province>?,
                  _controllerKec.text,
                  // _controller16.text as List<Province>?,
                  _controllerKel.text,
                  _controllerDusun.text,
                  _controllerRt.text,
                  _controllerRw.text,
                  _controllerKdPos.text,
                  _controllerNoHp.text,
                  _controllerEmail.text,
                  _controllerKps.text,
                  _controllerNoKps.text,
                  // _controller26.text as List<Trans>?,
                  _controllerTrans.text,
                  // _controller28.text as List<Jn>?,
                  _controllerJnsTinggal.text,
                  // _controller30.text as int?,
                  _controllerNmAyah.text,
                  _controllerNikAyah.text,
                  _controllerTglLhrAyah.text,
                  _controllerPendidikanAyah.text,
                  // _controller35.text as List<PendidikanAyah>?,
                  _controllerPekerjaanAyah.text,
                  _controllerPenghasilanAyah.text,
                  _controllerNmIbu.text,
                  _controllerNikIbu.text,
                  _controllerTglLhrIbu.text,
                  _controllerPekerjaanIbu.text,
                  // _controller42.text as List<PendidikanIbu>?,
                  _controllerPekerjaanIbu.text,
                  _controllerPenghasilanIbu.text,
                  _controllerNmWali.text,
                  _controllerNikWali.text,
                  _controllerTglLhrWali.text,
                  _controllerPendidikanWali.text,
                  // _controller49.text as List<PendidikanWali>?,
                  _controllerPekerjaanWali.text,
                  _controllerPekerjaanWali.text,
                );
              });
            },
            child: const Text('Update Data'),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: If the API does not allow null - why are you allowing it then? First - use 'String' not 'String?'. If you need to default some value, do that; or force the user to enter it.  Second thing is - get the output of your jsonEncode function - get the actual string; and run it in a tool like Postman to validate if you are getting the right response from the API. If not - figure out which field is wrong, and work your way back. Your question is how to send data with post in flutter - but you are sending it. The real question is - how to prepare the payload for my API; and only you would know that.

Comment: What is this API? Any sane API will allow you to auto-generate a code file for use in the client. You *do not* have to write this by hand. Just imagine the pain to actually do this for a whole API, and then it changes and you have to figure that all out manually. No. This API *will* have a means for you to auto-generate this code. You need to find it. Maybe it's Swagger/OpenAPI? Ask the API provider.

Comment: @Andrija I've tried it but the error still occurs like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the `response.statusCode` is not `201` but `200` instead. We need to check what's the status code. Please use the following code instead and paste the results if it doesn't work:

```dart
if (response.statusCode ~/100 == 2) {
      return UserBiodata.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode)
      print(response.body)
      throw Exception('Failed update data!');
    }
```

Comment: no, the status code is correct 201

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is it doesn't allow `null` values , then in your `Model` it would be preferred if you use `non-null` types.

Example:

```
//String? stAgama,
String stAgama, // Remove nullable operator
String stKwn,   

....
String <non_nullable_variable>
```

And even make sure you fill the `String` types with empty string if `null` in `jsonEncode`

Example:

```
 jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        "st_agama": stAgama ?? '', // assigning empty string if null
        'st_kwn': stKwn ?? '',
       
        '<non_nullable_variable>': <null_value> ?? ''
```

Comment: still, no change
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Olj5ZUx2twOW-kIcUg_JTflke2RuT6i4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing null exception due to passing null parameters,  you can check null values in below map.

```
Future<UserBiodata> sendBiodata(
      String? stAgama,
      // List<Agama>? agama,
      String? stKwn,
      // List<Kwn>? kwn,
      String? tempat,
      String? tglLahir,
      String? nik,
      String? nisn,
      String? npwp,
      String? jalan,
      String? stProv,
      // List<Province>? province,
      String? stKab,
      // List<Province>? kab,
      String? stKec,
      // List<Province>? kec,
      String? desa,
      String? dusun,
      String? rt,
      String? rw,
      String? kodePos,
      dynamic telp,
      String? email,
      String kps,
      String? stTrans,
      // List<Trans>? trans,
      String? stJn,
      // List<Jn>? jn,
      String? ipk,
      // int? smt,
      String? namaAyah,
      String? nikAyah,
      String? tglLahirAyah,
      String? stPendidikanAyah,
      // List<PendidikanAyah>? pendidikanAyah,
      String? pekerjaanAyah,
      String? penghasilanAyah,
      String? namaIbu,
      String? nikIbu,
      String? tglLahirIbu,
      String? stPendidikanIbu,
      // List<PendidikanIbu>? pendidikanIbu,
      String? pekerjaanIbu,
      String? penghasilanIbu,
      String? namaWali,
      String? nikWali,
      String? tglLahirWali,
      String? stPendidikanWali,
      // List<PendidikanWali>? pendidikanWali,
      String? pekerjaanWali,
      String? penghasilanWali,
      ) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/biodata/update',
      ),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        if(stAgama!=null)
        "st_agama": stAgama,
        
        if(stKwn!=null)
        'st_kwn': stKwn,
        // 'kwn': kwn,
        if(tempat!=null)
        "tempat": tempat,
        if(tglLahir!=null)
          "tgl_lahir": tglLahir,
        if(nik!=null)
          "nik": nik,
        if(nisn!=null)
          "nisn": nisn,
        if(npwp!=null)
          "npwp": npwp,
        if(jalan!=null)
          "jalan": jalan,
        if(stProv!=null)
          "st_prov": stProv,
        // 'province': province,
        if(stKab!=null)
          "st_kab": stKab,
        // 'kab': kab,
        if(stKec!=null)
          "st_kec": stKec,
        // 'kec': kec,
        if(desa!=null)
          "desa": desa,
        if(dusun!=null)
          "dusun": dusun,
        if(rt!=null)
          "rt": rt,
        if(rw!=null)
          "rw": rw,
        if(kodePos!=null)
          "kode_pos": kodePos,
        if(telp!=null)
          "telp": telp,
        if(email!=null)
          "email": email,
        if(kps!=null)
          "kps": kps,
        if(stTrans!=null)
          "st_trans": stTrans,
        if(stJn!=null)
        "st_jn": stJn,
        // "jn": jn,
        if(ipk!=null)
          "ipk": ipk,
        // "smt": smt,
        if(namaAyah!=null)
          "nama_ayah": namaAyah,
        if(nikAyah!=null)
          "nik_ayah": nikAyah,
        if(tglLahirAyah!=null)
          "tgl_lahir_ayah": tglLahirAyah,
        if(stPendidikanAyah!=null)
          "st_pendidikan_ayah": stPendidikanAyah,
        // "pendidikan_ayah": pendidikanAyah,
        if(pekerjaanAyah!=null)
          "pekerjaan_ayah": pekerjaanAyah,
        if(penghasilanAyah!=null)
          "penghasilan_ayah": penghasilanAyah,
        if(namaIbu!=null)
          "nama_ibu": namaIbu,
        if(nikIbu!=null)
          "nik_ibu": nikIbu,
        if(tglLahirIbu!=null)
          "tgl_lahir_ibu": tglLahirIbu,
        if(stPendidikanIbu!=null)
          "st_pendidikan_ibu": stPendidikanIbu,
        
        // "pendidikan_ibu": pendidikanIbu,
        if(pekerjaanIbu!=null)
          "pekerjaan_ibu": pekerjaanIbu,
        if(penghasilanIbu!=null)
          "penghasilan_ibu": penghasilanIbu,
        if(namaWali!=null)
          "nama_wali": namaWali,
        if(nikWali!=null)
          "nik_wali": nikWali,
        if(tglLahirWali!=null)
          "tgl_lahir_wali": tglLahirWali,
        if(stPendidikanWali!=null)
          "st_pendidikan_wali": stPendidikanWali,
        // "pendidikan_wali": pendidikanWali,
        if(pekerjaanWali!=null)
          "pekerjaan_wali": pekerjaanWali,
        if(penghasilanWali!=null)
          "penghasilan_wali": penghasilanWali,
      }),
    );

    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      return UserBiodata.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed update data!');
    }
  }
```

Comment: still, it doesn't work

Comment: what is error, please share that error with us. we will try our best to help you.

Comment: this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Olj5ZUx2twOW-kIcUg_JTflke2RuT6i4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

```
void postData() async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri), body: {
      "title": "Anything",
      "body": "Post body",
      "userid": "1",
    });
    debugPrint(response.statusCode.toString());
  }
```

Comment: do i not need to add parameter in postData function?

Comment: it depends, if your funcation can access variables easily then no need to add parameter else better to use parameters you can also use modal class to do it in more clean and efficient way.

Comment: How is this helping the OP to send non-string parameters?